# Path expected for join HQL - Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have the following HQL

```
.createQuery("select dl from DocumentLink dl " +
                    "left join DigitalFile df on df.iddigitalfile = dl.parentId and dl.entity.identity =:entityId " +
                    "where (dl.entity.identity =:entityId && dl.parentId =: parentId) || " +
                    "(df.entity.identity =:entityId and df.parentId =: parentId) ", DocumentLink.class);
```

Desired SQL Query:

```
select * from documentlink dl
        left join digitalfile df on df.iddigitalfile = dl.ParentId and dl.entity = 261
        where (dl.entity = 5 and dl.parentId = 39845) OR (df.entity = 5 and df.parentId = 39845);
```

When I run this query in Hibernate environment, I got the following stack trace.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select dl from com.raetsmarine.raetsbase3.domain.DocumentLink dl left join DigitalFile df on df.iddigitalfile = dl.parentId and dl.entity.identity =:entityId where (dl.entity.identity =:entityId and dl.parentId =: parentId)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
```

Do you have any suggestion how can I convert it in a proper way?

Comment: Learn how joins work in HQL, by reading the documentation? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: Why do you need the `on` clause in the join?

Comment: @JimmyB I used the keyword "with" instead of "on" but I got the same error.

Comment: I mean: Why do you need to specify the join criteria at all? JPA should be able to do it for you, unless you have some special join criteria which JPA is not aware of.

Comment: Btw, `and dl.entity.identity =:entityId` makes no sense in the join.

Comment: Look at ["JPQL Identification Variables"](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_from_vars). There you can see how to identify a path with a variable to use. A little down the page you find `SELECT DISTINCT art.author FROM Magazine AS mag, IN(mag.articles) art`. Try and alias the path to `dl.entity` this way.

Comment: I changed to this query but I got an exception
...QuerySyntaxException: An AnyType attribute cannot be join fetched
`select distinct dl from DocumentLink as dl join fetch dl.documentMetaData as dmd join fetch dmd.publishedBy join fetch dmd.documentLinkSet as dmddl join fetch dmd.documentType as dt left join fetch dl.parentEntityObject as peo with (peo.parentId=261)
where (dl.entity.identity = 261 and dl.parentId= :parentId) or (dl.entity.identity = :entityId and dl.parentId= :parentId),DocumentLink.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are two classes

```
@Getters
@Setters
public class A {
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    B b
}
```

and

```
@Getters
@Setters
public class B {
    Long id;
    Long someAttribute;
}
```

Then join in an HQL will look like

```
SELECT a FROM A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN a.b
WHERE b.someAttribute = 'Any Value'
```

Notice that the name of the class has been omitted and rather the name of the field has been used in the HQL without actually providing the `ON` `clause`.